# Fire trigger after commit on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm writing sql trigger that updates some columns in table. I have to write that this trigger fires only after commit. I read some articles about this topic but in the most it is said to use procedure. But I have to do it with trigger.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_reset_er_encours
 AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON T
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF (:NEW.T.var1)=0
 THEN UPDATE T 
  SET var1=NULL
 END IF;
 END;
```

Comment: "But I have to do it with trigger." Why?

Comment: My boss told me to.

Comment: Ask your boss to explain why and get them to give you an example of how to implement it.

Comment: As Littlefoot said, this doesn't really make sense from a transactional point of view, so you really need to clarify what you're trying to achieve and why (by asking your boss). Also verify that you're really supposed to update every row in the table to null, not just the row the trigger fired for.

Comment: My boss said that the body is ok and to use ON COMMIT. Where i need to put it ?

Comment: `ON COMMIT` only has relevance for temporary tables and materialised views - not for triggers. I don't know what your boss is referring to.

Comment: You can search the [`CREATE TABLE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B) and see that `ON COMMIT` is not valid syntax (and the word `commit` is only mentioned once in that page and that is with regards to database events and, in that case, the trigger is fired as an autonomous transaction).

Answer (score 1):

Trigger fires `after insert or update` on the `t` table. You can't (at least, as far as I can tell) *instruct* it to fire after commit.

Apart from that, rewrite it to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr_reset_er_encours
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON t
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (new.var1 = 0)
BEGIN
   :new.var1 := NULL;
END;
```

as updating the same table on which trigger fires results in the *mutating table* error.

---

Saying that you read that procedure should be used: basically, you should commit at the end of the transaction. It is pointless to

- do something (in the procedure)
- commit
- do something else
- never commit again (as you'll lose what you did in "something else")

Comment: That code is ok but my trigger need to check the value for 4 different columns and if they are 0 to set them to NULL. The body of my trigger is ok, but my boss tell me set this trigger fires after commit.

Comment: You can't assign a value to a `:new` field in an after trigger. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2xWqb-Kn)

Comment: Ah! Thank you, @Alex. Валентин, no problem in checking 4 columns, but - you just can't set trigger to fire after commit ...